# Is this SLA battery still usable?

Tags: batteries

[image: CSB battery]
[image: date code]

Hi everyone,

I had recently received a lot of SLA batteries. A bunch of 12V 7Ah Portalac APC batteries, which seems to be in good condition after testing. Also I had received three 6V 12AH batteries. A Fiamm-GS(it's kinda dead), but the other two CSB batteries seems to charge. But the issue is that after full charge and keeping it for a few days the battery voltage settles down to 6.33V and 6.35V for two batteries and then pretty much stays like that for quite a while. And it doesn't discharge either too quick when connected to a load.

So is the battery still okay? The date code as shown in picture says 991109M2. I'm not sure if it means 1992 & 2011.

Comment: Measure its capacity (at, say, the C/20 rate, that would be 7/20 Amps) - how long does it take to discharge? Don't let it get below about 11V and recharge it immediately, they don't like being left discharged.

Comment: Those are 6V batteries (3 cells). Do not try to charge them to 11V!

Comment: Riight, the question mentions both 12V and 6V and I misread... discharge down to about 5.5V then.

Comment: I'll try a discharge test and see how much capacity is left with the above mentioned test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A battery has to pass several tests to be 'not dead'.

Settling to an open circuit voltage of 6.3(ish) volts, and staying there, is a good first sign.

You should also check the capacity. These batteries are specified at the 20hr rate. That doesn't mean you can't discharge them faster, but that you'll only get the specified capacity at that rate. 12Ah/20 is 600mA. After a full charge, discharge them down to 5.5v. You would expect the capacity to be a substantial fraction of 12Ah.

Comment: I have both the batteries with me but one of them has bulged and cracked the case. So , I have kept it aside to be send for recycling. One of them is still okay though. I just use it now to power my transistor radio. But wouldn't running the battery down to 5.5V ruin it (in my case probably ruin it completely)? I had tested it back when I posted with a GE 4510 25W 6.4V bulb. The battery that I'm currently using on my radio seemed to hold kinda good. I was trying to see how the voltage dropped on initial load application.